# Python, list comprehension, filter single element in the list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Very often, when programming in Python, I need to filter the single element in the list.

For this I am using following code pattern:

```py
user1 = {'email': 'admin@example.io', 'role': 'admin'}
user2 = {'email': 'xuser@example.io', 'role': 'user'}
user3 = {'email': 'yuser@example.io', 'role': 'user'}
users = [user1, user2, user3]

temp = [x for x in users if x['role'] == 'admin']
admin = temp[0] if temp else None
```

Is there more elegant Pythonic way to fit the last two lines into the one ?

Comment: What's wrong with [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)?

Comment: Don't build the list; `next(<generator expression>, None)`.

Comment: I would suggest you to use classes. It's a little bit more work first but will save you much time when extending your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
admin = next((x for x in users if x['role'] == 'admin'), None)
print(admin)
```

**Output**

```
{'email': 'admin@example.io', 'role': 'admin'}
```